Our updated android studio failed to creating build?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error type: ErrorScope{Error scope for class <ERROR CLASS> with arguments: org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.IndexedParametersSubstitution@e36f71b}
[ERROR : ArrayList<ArticleInfo>]
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.SimpleTypeImpl.<init>(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:225)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleTypeWithNonTrivialMemberScope(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleType(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.KotlinTypeFactory.simpleType$default(KotlinTypeFactory.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace(TypeSubstitution.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace(TypeSubstitution.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.TypeSubstitutionKt.replace$default(TypeSubstitution.kt:140)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.util.TypeUtilsKt.replaceAnonymousTypeWithSuperType(typeUtils.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.util.TypeUtilsKt.replaceAnonymousTypeWithSuperType(typeUtils.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.util.TypeUtilsKt.replaceAnonymousTypeWithSuperType(typeUtils.kt:50)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.KaptAnonymousTypeTransformer.transformAnonymousType(f1954b914f1669a22500985f5333d227/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-2.0.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0..kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorResolver.transformAnonymousTypeIfNeeded(DescriptorResolver.java:1064)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver$resolveTypeNullable$1.invoke(VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.kt:95)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver$resolveTypeNullable$1.invoke(VariableTypeAndInitializerResolver.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.DeferredType.getDelegate(DeferredType.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.types.WrappedType.getAnnotations(KotlinType.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:109)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.doForceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:669)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.lambda$new$4(LazyClassDescriptor.java:220)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.descriptors.LazyClassDescriptor.forceResolveAllContents(LazyClassDescriptor.java:657)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.doForceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ForceResolveUtil.forceResolveAllContents(ForceResolveUtil.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension$doAnalysis$1.invoke(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doForEachDeclaration(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.extensions.PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.doAnalysis(PartialAnalysisHandlerExtension.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.doAnalysis(Kapt3Extension.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:301)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:113)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:292)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:172)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:93)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:471)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:367)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:309)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:623)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1718)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

SDK Version
Android Studio koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1

This question is similar to: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SimpleTypeImpl should not be created for error type. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
